# How to change the default font & font size in Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs, formatting, text-formatting

I really hate Arial, which happens to be the default for Google Docs.  Does anyone know if there is a way to change the default font and font size in Google Docs?  Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Open Google Docs 
In Menu bar Click on the Format

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those screen shots are pretty unreadable. Can you crop them to show the salient information?